# Perl MindMelting uninitialized variable in scalar from array exception

Tags: arrays, string, perl, hashmap, initialization

I had a hard time titleing this question, as I am truly stumped as to what could be causing this error.

when I have the code typed as such:

```
my @strArray= ('TypeKey', 'AccidentType', '01');
my %HashArrayThing = ('EnglishArray' => @strArray, 
        'FrenchArray' => ('julier', 'aout', 'septembre'));
my $scalar = @HashArrayThing{EnglishArray};
my @ARR = @HashArrayThing{EnglishArray};
say $scalar,
say $ARR[0];
```

the output is:

```
TypeKey
TypeKey1
```

when I change ONLY the `say $ARR[0]` to `say $ARR[1]` (or any other number) I get the error: "Uninitialized value in say at line 50"(same line as the 'say $scalar')

This makes no sense to me. I could understand that the $ARR[1] could be out of bounds having maybe olny gotten the first value from the array stored in the hashset, but I don't understand at all where this is coming from. 
I hope there is someone out there with a thourough understanding of perl who can enlighten me.

PS. also where is the '1'coming from that is bieng added to typekey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
my %HashArrayThing = ('EnglishArray' => @strArray, 
    'FrenchArray' => ('julier', 'aout', 'septembre'));
```

is actually creating this structure:

```
(
      'AccidentType' => '01',
      'FrenchArray' => 'julier',
      'EnglishArray' => 'TypeKey',
      'aout' => 'septembre'
)
```

where I imagine you were expecting:

```
(
      'FrenchArray'  => ['julier', 'aout', 'septembre'],
      'EnglishArray' => ['TypeKey', 'AccidentType', '01'],
)
```

This is happening because the *value* of a key/value pair in a Hash *must* be a SCALAR. So it is a simple value like a number or a string or a *reference* to Hash or an Array.

The following is the correct way to initialize your Hash:

```
my %HashArrayThing = (
    'EnglishArray' => [@strArray], 
    'FrenchArray'  => ['julier', 'aout', 'septembre']
);
```

Notice that the arrays you passed in previously are now wrapped in `[]` which creates a reference to an array.

Answer (score 1):

A hash pair `key => value` needs to have scalars for `key` and `value`.  Having an array for either doesn't make sense.

Hash is a list with an even number of elements in which each pair of two consecutive elements forms a key-value pair. For example, the following two hashes are exactly the same

```
my %h1 = ('one', 1, 'two', 2);  # $h1{'one'} --> 1
my %h2 = (one => 1, two => 2);  # same
```

The *fat comma* `=>` is a [`synonym for a comma`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) which also makes a bareword to its left quoted.

So when you say

```
my %HashArrayThing = ('EnglishArray' => @strArray, 
    'FrenchArray' => ('julier', 'aout', 'septembre'));
```

the whole list gets flattened and you assign to `%HashArrayThing` the following list

```
('EnglishArray', 'TypeKey', 'AccidentType', '01', 
 'FrenchArray', 'julier', 'aout', 'septembre')
```

Being assigned to a `%` variable this *is* a hash, with the funny (unintended) pairing of consecutive elements into key-value pairs -- so `EnglishArray` is a key and its value is `TypeKey`, etc. That is, if the number of elements happens to be even.  If the number is odd you'll get the warning -- but you still get the hash as well. So keep your warnings on, as always.

---

For packing arrays into a hash you need to use references,

```
my %HashArrayThing = ('EnglishArray' => \@strArray, 
    'FrenchArray' => ['julier', 'aout', 'septembre']);
```

Note that `\@` takes the reference of an existing array, so if the `@strArray` changes later that will be reflected in the hash. On the other hand, the `[...]` creates an *anonymous array*, copying listed values. Which is better suited for the purpose at hand depends on what your code does with this.

Then you access elements by dereferencing, for example

```
$HashArrayThing{'EnglishArray'}->[0];  # is 'TypeKey'
$HashArrayThing{'FrenchArray'}->[0];   # is 'julier'
```

For references see [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [`perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), while [`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) is a basic cookbook of complex (nested) data structures.